# How to command-line compile with files in a parent directory?

Tags: c++, command-line, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, g++

I'm attempting to compile a C++ program from the Terminal in Mac OS X 10.7.5, but I'm running into some errors. I have a folder which stores my debugging tests, and I'm storing the files I have to `#include`.

The files are as follows: `testCard.cpp`, `card.cpp`, and `card.h`.

When I try and compile as follows, attempting to use the `-I` flag to put the parent directory as the first file in the search path:

```
g++ -g -Wall testCard.cpp card.cpp -I..
```

I receive the error:

```
card.cpp: No such file or directory
```

Even though card.cpp is included in the parent directory. I have also tried the `-L` and `-isystem` flags, and neither work. How does one add the parent directory to the search path for command-line compilation?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm assuming this means the parent directory is automatically in the search path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Even though card.cpp is included in the parent directory.

`-I` affects the search path for includes; it does *not* affect where the source file inputs are looked up, at all.

So:

```
g++ -g -Wall testCard.cpp ../card.cpp -I..
```